# html grid not styling correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a basic grid that I'm trying to make using simple `<div>` tags, the problem is though that there is extra space at the bottom of the rows.  To better explain my problem, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2BZ5/1/).

Does anyone know why there is extra space at the bottom of the rows when the columns work perfectly fine?  and a little extra advise:  the height is 4.5555555 because the border is one pixel thick, and the bottom row doesn't have a border.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4.555 will round, you can always use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Do you need the divs to create the grid? Why not using something like a canvas?

Comment: I need to easily manipulate the amount of rows and/or columns, and why does repeating decimals work elsewhere? and i also dont see how that link would help my situation.

Comment: part of the issue is due to your elements are inline-block and you have white space in between each div

Comment: hence the font-size: 0px;  i noticed that a long time ago, and it made the bars go off the image, not leave space at the bottom.

Comment: you didn't have to remove your entire answer, it still had useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using pixles, you can use percentages, as pointed out by Huangism decimals will be truncated:

```
.row{
    height: 5.555555%;
}
```